# How to select records with minimum count() using LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql

Using the following query, I get a list of all pages and the number of visitors.

```
SELECT 
 pages.id AS id,
 count(visitors.id) AS volume
FROM pages
 LEFT JOIN visitors ON 
 pages.id = visitors.page_id
GROUP BY pages.id
ORDER BY volume DESC
```

This successfully returns something like

```
+--+------+
|id|volume|
+--+------+
|1 |288   |
|2 |355   |
|3 |80    |
etc...
```

Now, I just want to select the pages in which the volume (the number of visitor rows) is over 100.

I tried this:

```
SELECT 
 pages.id AS id,
 count(visitors.id) AS volume
FROM pages
 LEFT JOIN visitors ON 
 pages.id = visitors.page_id
WHERE
 volume > 100
GROUP BY pages.id
ORDER BY volume DESC
```

But that results in an error: #1054 - Unknown column 'volume' in 'where clause'

Using *WHERE count(visitors.id) > 100* gives the same error. How can I filter these results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `count(visitors.id)` in a having clause:

```
SELECT 
    pages.id AS id,
    count(visitors.id) AS volume
FROM pages
LEFT JOIN visitors ON pages.id = visitors.page_id
GROUP BY pages.id
HAVING count(visitors.id) > 100
ORDER BY volume DESC
```

Comment: That results in the error: #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT 
 pages.id AS id,
 count(visitors.id) AS volume
FROM pages
 LEFT JOIN visitors ON 
 pages.id = visitors.page_id
GROUP BY pages.id
HAVING count(visitors.id) > 200
ORDER BY volume DESC
```

You can think of HAVING clauses filtering results based on the aggregated results of the GROUP BY.